# What is the name of this event in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

What is the name of this event of jQuery in this page:

https://stackoverflow.com/about
Note that the animation is played (when I review a specific part of the page).

Also another example in Facebook, the content refreshes automatically when I just review the page or review the browser tab that contains it.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern is known as "scroll spy".

Answer (score 0):

You can either track the `scroll` event, i.e.

```
$(window).on('scroll', ...);
```

or use polling to peek continuously at `$(window).scrollTop()` to find the current position of the page relative to the top.

Comment: Could you provide a small example about 3 elements in different locations in the page